# How to make radiobutton button and text inline

Tags: android, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I'm using custom radiobutton . this is the image of my current radiobutton . as you can see , the button is much lower then the text .
How can I make them inline ?

[image]

this is the drawable xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/checkedradiobutton" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/unchekedradiobutton" android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: you can set gravity="center-vertical" for your radiobutton in xml

Comment: Don't answer here @MHP

Answer (score 2):

Use `android:gravity="center"`

```
 <RadioButton 
       android:text="@string/day" 
       android:id="@+id/jour"              
       android:gravity="center"
       android:checked="true">
 </RadioButton>
```

to center your text.

Answer (score 2):

you can use gravity in your RadioButton tag

```
<RadioButton 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
   android:gravity="center-vertical|right"<!--allow text position in center vertically-->
   android:button="@null"<!--disable default radio button(it's default position is to the left of text)-->
   android:drawableRight="@android:drawable/btn_radio"<!--put radioButton to right of text-->>
</RadioButton>
```